# What exactly is a "Node core object"?

Tags: node.js

I expect a definition. I sometimes read about "node core objects" in NodeJs tutorials or books but I don't find any previous explenation about them.

Comment: Maybe share a link or a quote that shows the term being used? Not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is based on JavaScript. And as you might know, JavaScript doesn't full fledge support OOPS to that greater extent. Node's core modules don't use object streams, partly because there aren't any real use cases yet. However, we can make use of object streams in our own code by using the objectMode option.When in objectMode, streams can push Strings and Buffers as well as any other JavaScript object. Another major difference is that when in objectMode, the internal buffering algorithm counts objects rather than bytes. This means if we have a Transform stream with the highWaterMark option set to 5, the stream will only buffer a maximum of 5 objects internally.
For example:-

```
var through2 = require('through2')
var split2 = require('split2')

var stream = through2({ objectMode: true }, function(chunk, enc, callback) {
    var string = chunk.toString()
    var result = string.replace(/\n/, '').toUpperCase().split(/[ \t]/)

    this.push(result)
    callback()
})

stream.on('data', function(data) {
    var toString = Object.prototype.toString.call(data)
    console.log('type of data:', toString)
    console.log('data:', data, '\n')
})

process.stdin
    .pipe(split2())
    .pipe(stream)
```

Output will be:-

```
Hello world
type of data: [object Array]
data: ["HELLO", "WORLD"]

Transform streams are great!
type of data: [object Array]
data: ["TRANSFORM", "STREAMS", "ARE", "GREAT!"]
```